# powerapps cannot use tab key to go to date picker

Tags: powerapps

I have several text datacards and a date picker.  When I press tab it ignores the date picker.  How can I fix this?
I've looked at the tab index for the controls and they are all zero.  Here is a screenshot.

[image: powerapp screen with date picker]

Comment: Can you please share a snapshot of you UI please

Comment: Usually, this could happen if the `Y` component of your Control (DatePicker) is lower than its adjacent controls. Then pressing the tab button could skip it.

Comment: Did you unlock the data card of date control and modify it's properties?

Comment: The Y component of the date picker has the same Y as they Y component of the textbox to its left.  It's the Y component of the label plus the height of the label.  The labels are the same height.  I have unlocked the data card of the date control.